# $|f(x)|$ is constant if and only if $f'(x) h$ is orthogonal to $f(x)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the following question:

> Let $f:U \to \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$, where $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ is an open connected set, be a differentiable function. Show that $|f(x)|$ is constant if and only if $f'(x)h$ is orthogonal to $f(x)$ for every $x \in U$ and $h \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

I was able to show that if $|f(x)|$ is constant then $f'(x)h \cdot f(x) = 0$. What about the other implication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the relation that you most likely already used:
$$
\nabla |f(x)|^2 \cdot h = 2 f'(x)h\cdot f(x).
$$
If $|f|$ is constant, then LHS is $0$. If $f'(x)h\perp f(x) \ \forall h$, then the RHS is $0$, so we are done.